# Test failure in Spring 5.1

Tags: spring, spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactive-streams, reactor-netty

I tried to upgrade my sample codes to 5.1 and Spring Boot 2.1. The Reactor Netty is refactored in the new version, some APIs are changed, I changed my codes according to the new version of Reactor Netty.

`HttpServer` for Reactor Netty.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:application.properties", ignoreResourceNotFound = true)
public class Application {

    @Value("${server.port:8080}")
    private int port = 8080;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        try (AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(
            Application.class)) {
            context.getBean(HttpServer.class).bindNow().onDispose().block();
        }
    }

    @Profile("default")
    @Bean
    public HttpServer nettyHttpServer(ApplicationContext context) {
        HttpHandler handler = WebHttpHandlerBuilder.applicationContext(context).build();
        ReactorHttpHandlerAdapter adapter = new ReactorHttpHandlerAdapter(handler);
        HttpServer httpServer = HttpServer.create().host("localhost").port(this.port);
        return httpServer.handle(adapter);
    }

}
```

IntegrationTest:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
public class IntegrationTests {

    @Value("${server.port:8080}")
    int port;

    WebTestClient rest;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        this.rest = WebTestClient
            .bindToServer()
            .responseTimeout(Duration.ofDays(1))
            .baseUrl("http://localhost:" + this.port)
            .build();
    }

    @Test
    public void getAllPostsWillBeOk() throws Exception {
        this.rest
            .get()
            .uri("/posts")
            .exchange()
            .expectStatus().isOk();
    }

}
```

When I ran the tests and I got the exception like this.

```
reactor.core.Exceptions$ReactiveException: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: no further information: localhost/127.0.0.1:8080

    at reactor.core.Exceptions.propagate(Exceptions.java:326)
    at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:131)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono.java:1498)
    at org.springframework.test.web.reactive.server.DefaultWebTestClient$DefaultRequestBodyUriSpec.exchange(DefaultWebTestClient.java:283)
    at com.example.demo.IntegrationTests.getAllPostsWillBeOk(IntegrationTests.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:84)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
    Suppressed: java.lang.Exception: #block terminated with an error
        at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:133)
        ... 34 more
Caused by: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: no further information: localhost/127.0.0.1:8080
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:327)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:340)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:616)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:563)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:480)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:442)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:884)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
    ... 10 more
```

**Updated**: Got it resolved by refactoring my testing codes.

```
@Autowired
HttpServer httpServer;

private DisposableServer disposableServer;

@Before
public void setup() {
    this.disposableServer = this.httpServer.bindNow();
    this.rest = WebTestClient
            .bindToServer()
            .responseTimeout(Duration.ofDays(1))
            .baseUrl("http://localhost:" + this.port)
            .build();
}

@After
public void teardown() {
    this.disposableServer.dispose();
}

@Test
public void getAllPostsWillBeOk() throws Exception {
    this.rest
            .get()
            .uri("/posts")
            .exchange()
            .expectStatus()
            .isOk();
}
```

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: @IanBurtovoy Resolved it, refactored my testing codes.